# bad resolution in android studio emulator after upgrading android studio to 2.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-2.3

I have an issue in android studio emulator after upgrade android studio to 2.3

the emulator is very very bad resolution

How to reset the resolution of the emulator ?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: How to reset the resolution of the emulator

Answer (score 2):

To change resolution of emulator:

Click on tools and select AVD Manager

[image: Click on tools and select AVD Manager]

Click the edit button on the device the little pen shown on the image below

[image: Click the edit button]

you will now see configuration of the device, click on change as show below

[image: click on change]

finally select a prefered harware with prefered resolution or click on new hardware profile, and set the resolution there

[image: resolution]

mark it as answer if its helpful

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I found the problem
the emulator displays pixels as 1x1 on your monitor.
My monitor is 27" FHD and the emulators that have the resolution more than my monitor, have this problem.
I tested the emulators that have low resolutions like 720x1520 or less (540x1080) now the problem has been solved and I have an almost clear and smooth screen on my emulators.
ofc I tested high resolutions like 1440x3044 and saw that the quality of the screens was worse than that lower resolutions.